# Two Interpreters Without Translator

Tags: translation, interpreter

I am having a hard time understanding this. 
Let I_L^M be an interpreter for language L that runs on machine M. Suppose you have access to a program, I_K^L , written in language L ,which is an interpreter for language K. Are you now able (without writing any additional translators or interpreters) to write and run programs in language K? Please explain.
I was thinking that it isn't possible because interpreters output byte code or something. It's very hard to understand and I think I'm overthinking it. Any help would be great!

Comment: If your "interpreter for language L" is unable to run a program "written in language L", then it's hardly an interpreter for language L, is it?

Comment: The interpreter for L can run. Says it runs on machine M.

Comment: Then why do you have trouble believing that an arbitrary program written in L is incapable of doing its job?

Comment: Because it's focusing on language K, not L.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to run programs in language `K`.

It might help to consider a specific example: let `L` be Python and let `K` be Lisp. `I_L^M` is the Python interpreter that you can obtain for your machine `M`, and use to run all kinds of Python programs. One such program is `I_K^L`, an interpreter for Lisp written in Python. Say it's in lisp.py. Then you would invoke:

    `python lisp.py`

The Python interpreter will start up, open lisp.py, and execute the Python code it finds there, which will (say) start a Lisp read-eval-print loop. Or you might invoke

    `python lisp.py fibonacci.lisp`

to have the Lisp interpreter run the Lisp code in fibonacci.lisp.

Since you mention byte code: it's likely that, internally, the Python program will translate lisp.py into byte code, and then execute *that*. However, that will be mostly invisible to you, other than the possible creation of a .pyc file to save time on subsequent runs.